# ListView set column header states

Tags: windows, winapi

How do I go about adding the up/down arrows to the column headers that indicate sorted ascending/descending?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`HDM_SETITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775367.aspx) and [`HDMITEM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775247.aspx), there is a `HDI_ORDER` flag and an `iOrder` field.
To get the `HWND` of the Header Control itself, use [`LVM_GETHEADER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774937.aspx).